# Efficient way to modify selected points in onRender() of htmlWidgets

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, htmlwidgets

I am working on an interactive graphic that plots black points for 2 quantitative variables (A and B). The user can select a threshold. After doing so, only point that are above that threshold magnitude get plotted and a gray rectangle that denotes the area in which the threshold did not pass also gets plotted. This all seems to be working fine.

However, what I am now trying to achieve is to allow the user to select certain points. When doing so, the selected points should turn from black to red. When the user selects a new subset of points, the previously-selected points return from red to black. In other words, the only points that appear red in the plot should be the ones last selected.

Unfortunately, this part does not seem to be working. The issues right now are:

1) The selected points remain red permanently.
2) If already-red points are selected, sometimes unselected black points become red. You can see an example of this error (in pictures) at the bottom of the post.

I believe this is happening because I simply plot a whole new trace of red points that correspond with the x and y values selected (This is below in the code commented as "// Add user-selected points in red"). Hence, the red points become their own entity.

My question is: What is an efficient way to solve this problem (so that selected points become red until another subset is selected?) I use the term efficient, because I am working with large datasets (100-1,000s points), and so I am looking for ways the save computational speed. It may be more efficient to simply modify the selected black points to red rather than entirely redraw superimposed red points? However, I am unsure how to achieve this using Plotly trace syntax.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Below is a simplified version of my script.

```
library(plotly)
library(GGally)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sliderInput("thresh", "Threshold:", min = 0, max = 3, value=1, step=1),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  textOutput("selectedValues")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  thresh <- reactive(input$thresh)

  set.seed(1)
  dat <- data.frame(Row = paste0("Row",sample(c(1:20),20)), A=4*rnorm(20), B=4*rnorm(20))
  dat$Row <- as.character(dat$Row)

  minVal = min(dat[,-1])
  maxVal = max(dat[,-1])

  gg <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x=A, y=B)) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(minVal, maxVal), ylim = c(minVal, maxVal))

  ggY <- ggplotly(gg)

  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly(ggY %>% onRender("
    function(el, x, data) {
    var Points = [];
    var Traces = [];
    var selRows = [];

    data.dat.forEach(function(row){
    if(Math.abs(row['B']) > data.thresh) selRows.push(row);});

    var xArr = [];
    var yArr = [];
    var keepIndex = [];
    for (a=0; a<selRows.length; a++){
      xArr.push(selRows[a]['A'])
      yArr.push(selRows[a]['B'])
      keepIndex.push(selRows[a]['Row'])
    }
    Points.push(keepIndex);

    // Add points above the threshold in black
    var tracePoints = {
      x: xArr,
      y: yArr,
      hoverinfo: 'none',
      mode: 'markers',
      marker: {
        color: 'black',
        size: 4
      }
    };

    // Add upper horizontal line of gray box
    var hiLine = {
      x: [-15,15],
      y: [data.thresh,data.thresh],
      mode: 'lines',
      line: {
        color: 'gray',
        width: 1
      },
      opacity: 0.25,
      hoverinfo: 'none'
    };

    // Add lower horizontal line of gray box
    var lowLine = {
      x: [-15,15],
      y: [-1*data.thresh,-1*data.thresh],
      mode: 'lines',
      fill: 'tonexty',
      line: {
        color: 'gray',
        width: 1
      },
      opacity: 0.25,
      hoverinfo: 'none'
    };

    Traces.push(tracePoints);
    Traces.push(hiLine);
    Traces.push(lowLine);
    Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);

    var idRows = []
    for (a=0; a<data.dat.length; a++){
      idRows.push(data.dat[a]['Row'])
    }

    el.on('plotly_selected', function(e) {
      numSel = e.points.length
      cN = e.points[0].curveNumber;

      var pointNumbers = [];
      var selData = [];
      for (a=0; a<numSel; a++){
        pointNumbers.push(e.points[a].pointNumber)
        selData.push(data.dat[idRows.indexOf(Points[0][pointNumbers[a]])])
      }
      Shiny.onInputChange('selData', selData);
      var Traces = [];
      var xArr = [];
      var yArr = [];
      for (a=0; a<selData.length; a++){
        xArr.push(selData[a]['A'])
        yArr.push(selData[a]['B'])
      }

      // Add user-selected points in red
      var traceRed = {
        x: xArr,
        y: yArr,
        mode: 'markers',
        marker: {
          color: 'red',
          size: 4
        },
        hoverinfo: 'none'
      };
      Traces.push(traceRed);

      Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);
    })

    }", data = list(dat=dat, thresh=thresh())))

  selData <- reactive(input$selData)
  output$selectedValues <- renderPrint({selData()})

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Below is an example of the error:

Say, I open the app with all its default, and I simply Plotly-select the top four right points. The result looks good because only those four points are colored red, as seen below:

[image: Picture 1]

Now, say I reselect those top four points. The result no longer looks good because even though those four points are colored red, two additional points have erroneously been colored red as well:

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easist way to deal with this is to simply keep track of if you have selected something, and delete the previous trace containing the selected points if there was a previous selection. To accomplish this the following changes were made:

- added a counter `nseltrace` to keep track of how often we have selected things
- added a `Plotly.deleteTraces` statement to delete the last trace (which can be specified with the index -1.
- that delete action is guarded by an `if (nseltrace>0)` statement.
- reformatted your selection points to put them in a data frame (they come over munged together as a character vector)
- used the `verbatumTextOutput` to print them out as it is a cleaner format.

#### Update:

- added a guard to only have it select points that belong to the`curveNumber` 1, i.e. the original data, not the selected traces that follow. This was causing already selected points to be entered in the newly selected list twice.

As to whether that is the most efficient way, obviously depends. You are plotting the selected points over there previous non-selected representations, worst case would be a factor of two, but point drawing is extremely fast and the typical slowdown for a smallish percentage of the points is likely not even measurable. I would not optimize this unless it proved to be a problem later, and then I would use the latest plotly as there is quite a lot of optimization (and bug removal) currently going on in the plotly code base.

Here is the code:

```
library(plotly)
library(GGally)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sliderInput("thresh", "Threshold:", min = 0, max = 3, value=1, step=1),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selectedValues")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  thresh <- reactive(input$thresh)

  set.seed(1)
  dat <- data.frame(Row = paste0("Row",sample(c(1:20),20)), A=4*rnorm(20), B=4*rnorm(20))
  dat$Row <- as.character(dat$Row)

  minVal = min(dat[,-1])
  maxVal = max(dat[,-1])

  gg <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x=A, y=B)) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(minVal, maxVal), ylim = c(minVal, maxVal))

  ggY <- ggplotly(gg)

  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly(ggY %>% onRender("
                                                 function(el, x, data) {
                                                 var Points = [];
                                                 var Traces = [];
                                                 var selRows = [];

                                                 data.dat.forEach(function(row){
                                                 if(Math.abs(row['B']) > data.thresh) selRows.push(row);});

                                                 var xArr = [];
                                                 var yArr = [];
                                                 var keepIndex = [];
                                                 for (a=0; a<selRows.length; a++){
                                                 xArr.push(selRows[a]['A'])
                                                 yArr.push(selRows[a]['B'])
                                                 keepIndex.push(selRows[a]['Row'])
                                                 }
                                                 Points.push(keepIndex);

                                                 // Add points above the threshold in black
                                                 var tracePoints = {
                                                 x: xArr,
                                                 y: yArr,
                                                 hoverinfo: 'none',
                                                 mode: 'markers',
                                                 marker: {
                                                 color: 'black',
                                                 size: 4
                                                 }
                                                 };

                                                 // Add upper horizontal line of gray box
                                                 var hiLine = {
                                                 x: [-15,15],
                                                 y: [data.thresh,data.thresh],
                                                 mode: 'lines',
                                                 line: {
                                                 color: 'gray',
                                                 width: 1
                                                 },
                                                 opacity: 0.25,
                                                 hoverinfo: 'none'
                                                 };

                                                 // Add lower horizontal line of gray box
                                                 var lowLine = {
                                                 x: [-15,15],
                                                 y: [-1*data.thresh,-1*data.thresh],
                                                 mode: 'lines',
                                                 fill: 'tonexty',
                                                 line: {
                                                 color: 'gray',
                                                 width: 1
                                                 },
                                                 opacity: 0.25,
                                                 hoverinfo: 'none'
                                                 };

                                                 Traces.push(tracePoints);
                                                 Traces.push(hiLine);
                                                 Traces.push(lowLine);
                                                 Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);

                                                 var idRows = []
                                                 for (a=0; a<data.dat.length; a++){
                                                 idRows.push(data.dat[a]['Row'])
                                                 }

                                                 var nseltrace = 0;
                                                 el.on('plotly_selected', function(e) {
                                                 console.log(e.points)
                                                 numSel = e.points.length

                                                 var pointNumbers = [];
                                                 var selData = [];
                                                 for (a=0; a<numSel; a++){
                                                   if (e.points[a].curveNumber==1){  // restrict to points in the original curve
                                                     pointNumbers.push(e.points[a].pointNumber)
                                                     selData.push(data.dat[idRows.indexOf(Points[0][pointNumbers[a]])])
                                                   }
                                                 }
                                                 Shiny.onInputChange('selData', selData);
                                                 var Traces = [];
                                                 var xArr = [];
                                                 var yArr = [];
                                                 for (a=0; a<selData.length; a++){
                                                 xArr.push(selData[a]['A'])
                                                 yArr.push(selData[a]['B'])
                                                 }

                                                 // Add user-selected points in red
                                                 var traceRed = {
                                                 x: xArr,
                                                 y: yArr,
                                                 mode: 'markers',
                                                 marker: {
                                                 color: 'red',
                                                 size: 4
                                                 },
                                                 hoverinfo: 'none'
                                                 };

                                                 if (nseltrace>0){
                                                 Plotly.deleteTraces(el.id,-1)
                                                 }
                                                 Traces.push(traceRed);
                                                 nseltrace = nseltrace+1

                                                 Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);
                                                 })

                                                 }", data = list(dat=dat, thresh=thresh())))

  selData <- reactive({
    req(input$selData)
    rawc <- input$selData
    df <- data.frame(t(matrix(rawc,nrow=3)))
    names(df) <- names(rawc)[1:3]
    df
  })
  output$selectedValues <- renderPrint({selData()})

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate the helpful ideas you provide. Unfortunately, I think the error that occurs when a user's selection contains any subset of already-red points remains however. I added an example (with images) at the bottom of my post. Thanks again.

Comment: When I use the code I pasted here that is not what I see. Each time I select the previous points go away. Did you use my code as posted?

Comment: Oh, ok, I see that problem now. It is different than before, reselection is somehow different. Let me look at that.

Comment: Thank you. The error is pretty sneaky, and it is in both your approach and my approach.

Comment: Yes, your posted code does solve the first issues I was having!